# General solution for bypassing file headers in shell commands

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I make extensive use of piping multiple linux shell commands, for example:

```
grep BLAH file1 | sed 's/old/new/' | sort -k 1,1 > file3
```

My files often have a header line, and often I have to preserve it throughout the pipeline. So, for example, I would want to grep, sed and sort from line 2 and on, while keeping the 1st line unchanged.

I am looking for some general solution that given some command(s) would preserve the header. I usually write the header to a file before the pipe and then cat it back after the pipe ends. I have started using zshell, so I was wondering if that might help to get a more streamlined solution.

Perhaps something like this:

[image]

(arrows are pipes in the image)

but I am not sure how to get that to work in zshell or if it is even possible. One problem is that I need to follow up the first pipe split with a command on both pipes.

Any creative solutions?

Comment: I'm not sure abouth zsh, but with bash you could use `(head -2 file1;tail -n +3 file1 | grep BLAH | sed 's/old/new/' | sort -k 1,1) >file3`

Comment: @Vaughn You seem to have factored in 2 lines of header.  You probably meant `(head -n +1 blah; tail -n +2 blah | sed 's/old/new' | sort -k 1,1) > outfile`

Comment: @devnull: You're right.  I'm used to working with files with two header lines and just used that without thinking.

Comment: +1 for providing a _useful_ image to illustrate your intention :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vaughn and devnull have already directed you towards the solution. They both contain typos though and I have some remarks to add and would advise to use this instead:

```
{ head -n 1 file1; tail -n +2 file1 | grep BLAH | sed 's/old/new/' | sort -k 1,1; } >file3
```

What it does is take the first line of `file1` in one command (your header) and does your `grep/sed/whatever` magic in a second command on the rest of the file (sans the header, `tail -n +2`) and redirects the *combined* output to `file3`.

Notes:

- If your shell supports `{ }` it is preferred over the `( )` construct in this case as it does not spawn a subshell (sometimes it is desirable to have the subshell, though).
- `head -2` is deprecated, you should use the `-n` parameter like `head -n 2`
- You can skip the `tail -n +2 file1` part if you absolutely know that what you are grepping for cannot be found in your header, but it is certainly cleaner this way.

This should work in most recent shells, btw (bash, ksh, zsh).